# Z factor to get the results in square meters and cubic meters?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, area, units, volume

I have a DEM surface in WGS 1984.I want to calculate surface area and volume in different elevations.I wonder for example If I want to measure the area and volume below some height how shall I set the Plane Height and Z factor to get the results in square meters and cubic meters?

Comment: Generally the vertical and horizontal units must be the same to do the kinds of operations you're talking about. There's no direct conversion factor from degrees to meters, so you probably need to project your DEM.